# GreaseMonkey Script

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

So I have this page with the html code and I want greasemonkey to replace it by another HTML code that I have. How can it be done ?

exemple I have

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Cajuda</h1>

<p>Oliveira da serra</p>
<p>Oliveira da serra</p>
<p>Oliveira da serra</p>
<p>Oliveira da serra</p>
<p>Lagarta maritima</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to transform in this :

```
    <html>
<body>
<td title="7885" nowrap="nowrap">Ovar</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td title="Online" align="center" bgcolor="#ff8288">H</td>
<td title="Offline" align="center" bgcolor="#88ff88">1</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of Same User's previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173727/greasemonkey-simple-script

Comment: Please explain this in more detail and maybe with an example.  If you don't add more detail it will probably get closed again.

Comment: Please update the original question instead of posting another copy of it.

Comment: I don't understand how you "transform" your first HTML code into the second HTML code - there is nothing similar between the 2 pieces of code except for the html and body tags.  Why not just create a new page with your second html code, and browse to that instead?

Comment: i want a transformation of the page thats all..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to tutorials on [How to write Greasemonkey scripts](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-write-greasemonkey-scripts.html).

Answer (score 1):

From the [greasemonkey manual](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/patterns/replace-element.html):

```
var theImage, altText;
theImage = document.getElementById('annoyingsmily');
if (theImage) {
    altText = document.createTextNode(theImage.alt);
    theImage.parentNode.replaceChild(altText, theImage);
}
```

The rest is available [here](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/).

Comment: that is to replace a certain image for a text totally different.